# What do the words " deep" and "off" in this context mean?

Tags: word-meaning

New French satellite images show possible debris from a missing Malaysian airliner deep in the southern Indian Ocean, Malaysia said on Sunday, adding to growing signs that the plane may have gone down in remote seas off Australia.
From reuters
http://mobile.reuters.com/article/topNews/idUSBREA2701720140323?irpc=932

My conception is that both"deep" and "off" means away from.  The word " deep" does not necessarily mean " deep in the water" . It says it went down. It is confusing. Previous satelite pictures has identified debris on the water not in the water.  Why the writer has written deep in the ocean.

Answer (score 1):

'Off' in the context given here, means 'situated or leading in a direction away from'.
Let us substiute this in the sentence to make it clearer.

> ..adding to growing signs that the plane may have gone down in remote seas ***situated in a direction away from*** Australia

'Deep', when used as an adverb (as it is here), means 'far down or in'

So our sentence becomes,

> New French satellite images show possible debris from a missing Malaysian airliner ***far down in*** the southern Indian Ocean...

Comment: And *deep*=*far down* doesn't mean vertical depth or distance down, it means horizontal 'depth', remoteness from land.

Comment: To aid visualization, I would say "deep in the forest" is similar to this usage of "deep in the southern Indian Ocean".